# How can extract table headers from PDF file using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have PDF with a table of high width, because of that table get split into multiple pages in PDF file.

I need to extract headers of table from all pages in a `List<String>`. Is there any good solution for this. Tried iTextSharp, but still not find a good solution.

Comment: if you tried can you some example or code ?

Answer (score -1):

You cab read the file with a `stream reader`, and you read the first line you can check whether it contains the %PDF header tag as below:

```
 Dim stream As New StreamReader("C:\Users\dbermudez\Desktop\docBOLR_0.pdf")
 Dim containsPDFHeader As Boolean = True

 If Not stream.ReadLine().Contains("%PDF") Then
     containsPDFHeader = False
 End If
```

Comment: This is not what the question asked for.

Comment: Need solution in C# only